# Get search text value in URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a form like this

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://domain.com">
    <input name="s" id="s" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

When I add some keyword on search input text, The URL is going as http://domain.com/?s=keyword

I need it as http://domain.com/?s=keyword&post_type=events

Means I need just &post_type=event added on url. How can I do it? any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="events">
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working. I will accept your answer in 8 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code...

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://domain.com">
    <input name="s" id="s" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" name="post_type" value='event'/>
</form>
```

When you press button it return to like.

```
http://domain.com/?s=keyword&post_type=events
```

Comment: Thank you. It is also working. Learned about name & value feature :)

Comment: This is not desirable. Hidden input field would be better. This also changes the text on submit button to `event`, whereas it is supposed to be `search`

Comment: You are right. I am using search icon on submit button so no problems. But yes, hidden will be better :)